# Pending intent returning same boolean values

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have a method that set different pending intents that passes a boolean value to the broadcast receiver through intents. But on the onRecieve method I am getting the same boolean value...

```
    public static void setNotification(Context ctx) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    cancelNotification(_instance);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationReceiver.class);
    Intent dataIntent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationReceiver.class);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (!Prefs.getInstance().isLoggedIn) {
        myIntent.putExtra("DATA", false);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, myIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 2 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        if (Prefs.getInstance().isDataReminder) {
            dataIntent.putExtra("DATA", true);
            dataPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0,
                    dataIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 3 * 60 * 1000,
                    dataPendingIntent);

        }
        if (Prefs.getInstance().reminderInterval.equals("1 Day")
                || Prefs.getInstance().reminderInterval.equals("")) {
            myIntent.putExtra("DATA", false);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 1000,
                    pendingIntent);
        } else {
            myIntent.putExtra("DATA", false);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5 * 60 * 1000,
                    pendingIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

Broadcast---

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean isDataReminder = intent.getBooleanExtra("DATA", false);
    Intent notificationService = new Intent(context,
            NotificationService.class);
    notificationService.putExtra("DATA", isDataReminder);
    context.startService(notificationService);
}
```

Does different pending intents can pass different values or do I need to change the approach?

Comment: use different requestCodes in PendingIntent.getBroadcast

Comment: Try to replace this code :pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, (int) (Math.random() * 100), myIntent, 0);

Comment: dont use random as it can result in same numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different *requestCode* for each of your `PendingIntent`s. The requestCode used to uniquely identify pending intents.